# Mixing Fowlers Transaction Script and Domain Model

Tags: design, vb.net

I am developing a large application where the previous developer used Martin Fowlers Transaction Script pattern.

The requirements are becoming more complex and it is becoming a bit of a maintenance nightmare. Therefore I have started to use Fowlers Domain Model and Table Data Gateway in an attempt to separate concerns and reuse code. It is becoming a refactoring process.

My question is: is it bad practice to mix and match patterns? e.g. using Transaction Script and Domain Model in the same application or is this relatively common practice?

Comment: I won't put a full blown answer as I'm short on time, but I'll say this. Considering a [3 layered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), the Transaction Script and Domain Model patterns both have the same purpose in the Logic tier. In very simple terms, you use a Transaction Script when the logic is simple and a Domain Model when it is complicated. In this case, I wouldn't suggest mixing and matching. For patterns in general it's fine.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, thanks. Just to be clear; are you saying dont mix and match the two patterns in the same app? Can you explain why if you have time?

Answer (score 5):

It is fine to mix domain logic patterns. A large system can be broken down into modules with domain logic patterns selected based on complexity of each module e.g. Complex stuff - Domain Model Pattern and simple stuff can use Transaction Script. If then you find some simple modules are beginning to become complex you can refactor to the domain model pattern. I cover this in a book I am writing at the moment https://leanpub.com/Practicing-DDD

Comment: Thanks +1.  Are you able to look at my other design pattern question here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205462/fowlers-data-access-layer-patterns ?

Answer (score 0):

In Fowler's book, it's acceptable to mix all patterns in one application ("Transaction Script", "Table Module" and "Domain Model").